# How to put each result of a MySQL query into a text file one by one?

Tags: php

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $row->products_price=$row->products_price-($row->products_price*0.05);
    echo $row->products_id ." ". $row->products_price."<br/>";
}
```

How can I put `$row->products_id ." ". $row->products_price` into a txt file with one row a time?

Comment: check the php manual for the functions fopen, fwrite, fclose etc. just http://php.net/fwrite and check the parameter for fopen to append

Comment: thank you, i don't know how to set the second argument of fwrite

Comment: check the manual page for fopen. php.net/fopen.. you already have an answer that shows you one way to do this.. if you don't want to truncate the existing content when you open the file you can use "a".. there are a lot of options.. check which one is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$content = "";
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($result) ){
    $row->products_price = $row->products_price-($row->products_price * 0.05);
    $content .=  $row->products_id . " " . $row->products_price . "\r\n";
}
file_put_contents("filename.txt", $content, LOCK_EX);
```

Edit: (a version for Hikaru-Shindo)

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($result) ){
    $row->products_price = $row->products_price-($row->products_price * 0.05);
    file_put_contents("filename.txt", $row->products_id . " " . $row->products_price . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: This would not write one row at a time but the whole at once.

Comment: Yes, and that's why it is better! It takes a lot longer to progress if you write one line after the other.

Comment: +1 I don't think he asked for one row at a time, but one by one (as in each result row in a new line)... @micha, I edited your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fh = fopen("myfile.txt", "w+");
while($row= mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
    $row->products_price=$row->products_price-($row->products_price*0.05);
    fwrite($fh, $row->products_id ." ". $row->products_price."\r\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: I think mode "w" should be sufficient, since only write operations are done. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Why don't you guys move to more modern functions? We have PHP5!!! http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: file_put_contents would work just as well... theres more than 1 way of achieving the same result ;)

Comment: New line is enough for *Nix systems through... MacOS uses \r and windows a combination of both (like done here)